# facebook addfriend.php redirects to an error page

Tags: facebook

I need to provide "Add Friend" link in my facebook connect application.

If I open the following file directly or if I type URL directly in a browser then I am able to achieve the same.

But when I open it in locahost (using apache server), it gets redirected to an error page on facebook with the message "You are sending friends requests that may be considered abusive.".

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/addfriend.php?id=123456789">Add Friend</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not do it from localhost or probably some other domain because facebook checks the referrer to this page, and therefore facebook won't allow adding friends this way.